# @font-face - problems with diacritic

Tags: css, cross-browser, font-face

I have a problem with CSS3 property for using my own fonts @font-face. In Chrome, Safari and IE10 browsers aren't any problems, but in other browsers there are several problems:

I used this code: (fonts Gabriola a monotype - same code for both)

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Gabriola";
    src: url("../fonts/Gabriola.eot?") format("eot"),
         url("../fonts/Gabriola.woff") format("woff"),
         url("../fonts/Gabriola.ttf") format("truetype"),
         url("../fonts/Gabriola.svg#Gabriola") format("svg");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

In Google Chrome everything is OK: [Screen](http://www.webpagescreenshot.info/img/933395-242012123728PM)

Firefox replace letters with diacritic with an other font - [Screen](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/408/firefoxo.png/)

Opera one of the included fonts doesn't display at all and the in the text with second one skip the letters with diacritic: [Screen](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/577/operas.png/)

In the new IE10 there's everything ok and the older ones (IE9 and IE8) are behaving like Firefox.

How can I repair this? Or at least replace the font-family in the problematic browsers with some universal font (like Arial, ...) and change the font-size property. For IE there are good hacks but how about Opera and Firefox?

Thank you!

Comment: Please format your code for readability when posting. `:)`

Comment: The `eot` and `woff` versions might be missing the characters – it's possible to only add a part of the original Truetype font's character set as needed on a given webpage to reduce download size, and whoever did the conversion might have only included Latin-1. Try and make your own `eof` and `woff` version.

Comment: (Also, the font is godawful for runs of text and UI elements. Just saying.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bad font file (without diacritics characters)... Solved.